# Ionic 3 in @Component, use variable from class

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, components

I'm trying to implement template for different app language.
1 approach I've came out with if possible, can I use variable from class to be defined in `@IonicPage() @Component` -> `templateUrl` ? My ts:

```
    @IonicPage()
    @Component({
      selector: 'page-mypage',
      templateUrl: {templatePath},
    })

    export class MyPage {
       templatePath;

       constructor(... , private storage: Storage) {
          storage.get('lang').then((langVal) => {
             this.templatePath = (langVal=='de') ? 'mypage_de.html' : 'mypage.html';
          });
       }
    }
```

Comment: It'd be better just to create different page for each language, and getting the current language before pushing that page, to check which page should be pushed based on that... If there are a lot of methods in common, you can extract them to be in a shared service, in order to avoid duplicating that code on each page. Another option could be to use the same page, but using `ngIf` to hide/show the right part of the template based on the current language.

Comment: You are right. I am using your suggested approach right now and works fine. It seems like my approach in the question is not possible in angular